# Why do I have to move the pointer by 2 using 'seekg' when it points at a new line symbol?

Tags: c++

Trying to parse the file:

```
1

2

3
```

It basically represents something like this: `1\n\n2\n\n3`. I want to skip a number of symbols and if a particual one is presented during this action, I should to return the pointer back. Further the first implementation is put forward:

```
void DoSomething(std::fstream &file, std::size_t num, char sym) {
  for (int i{}; i < num; ++i) {

    // if a symbol matches 'sym', return the pointer back otherwise keep on
    // reading
    if (file.peek() != sym) {
      file.seekg(1, std::ios::cur);
    } else {
      file.seekg(-i, std::ios::cur);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

As I shown before, there are only 7 symbols; when I called the function passing that file, num = 7, sym = '4', I figure out that 'DoSomething' do not even reach the '2' symbol in the file. To clarify this, I display some debug info in the terminal. Now the function looks like this:

```
void DoSomething(std::fstream &file, std::size_t num, char sym) {
  for (int i{}; i < num; ++i) {
    auto peek{static_cast<char>(file.peek())}; 

    // if a symbol matches 'sym', return the pointer back otherwise keep on
    // reading
    if (peek != sym) {
      file.seekg(1, std::ios::cur);
      std::cout << peek; // some debug info
    } else {
      file.seekg(-i, std::ios::cur);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

A call yields: `1\n\n\n\n\n\n` ('\n' - 6 times). But the problem turned out to be easy to fix. When the fucntion peeks '\n' symbol, move the pointer by 2, otherwise move by 1. The second attempt to implement:

```
void DoSomething(std::fstream &file, std::size_t num, char sym) {
  auto offset{0};

  for (int i{}; i < num; ++i) {
    auto peek{static_cast<char>(file.peek())}; 

    // if a symbol matches 'sym', return the pointer back otherwise keep on
    // reading
    if (peek != sym) {
      if (peek != '\n') { // checks if 'peek' equals '\n'
        file.seekg(1, std::ios::cur); // if it doesn't, move the pointer by 1
        ++offset;
      } else { // if it does, move the pointer by 2
        file.seekg(2, std::ios::cur);
        offset += 2;
      }    

      std::cout << peek;  // some debug info
    } else {
      file.seekg(-offset, std::ios::cur);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Now the function produces the results I want. For example:

```
  std::fstream file{"txt.txt", std::ios::in};

  std::cout << "The first call:\n";
  DoSomething(file, 7, '2');

  std::cout << "\nThe second call:\n";
  DoSomething(file, 7, '4');
```

Results:

```
The first call:
1


The second call:
1

2

3
```

The question is why do I have to move the pointer by 2 when it points at a new line symbol?

Comment: How do you open the file? There's a difference between _binary_ and _text_ files. It is possible that your `\n` characters are `\r\n` in the file (and seek may not skip the CR character).

Comment: On Windows, a new line consists of two characters `\r\n`, where `\r` is carriage return and `\n` is new line

Comment: I use only `std::ios::in` open flag while opening it: `std::fstream file{"txt.txt", std::ios::in};`

Comment: @Denis319199 then you are opening in text mode, which SHOULD automatically translate `\r\n` into `\n` when running on Windows. But that is dependent on the stream's implementation. But why are you using `peek()` and `seekg()` at all for *forward* progress? Why not just use `get()` instead, and then `seekg()` backwards when needed?

Comment: @Remy, I concur with you about using `get()`; I utilized `peek()` and `seek()` in order to provide the point I wanted to understand. But, anyway, I have to handle the case when `get()` returns a new line symbol because it is two symbols on Windows which makes the code not cross-platform. Does it mean that I should write two versions of the code: the first that considers `\n` as `\r\n` and the second that doesn't?

Comment: @Denis319199 "*I have to handle the case when `get()` returns a new line symbol because it is two symbols on Windows which makes the code not cross-platform*" - again, most stream implementations running on Windows will translate `\r\n` to `\n` for you. So your code will only ever see `\n`

Comment: @RemyLebeau but `seekg` does not care for that translation, so it only skips 1 byte which is '\r' and that's why `\n` is read again

Comment: @Slava then they would be a broken stream implementation and should be reported as a bug to the author.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I doubt that is a bug. Lets say I open 10G text file in text mode and seekg to the middle. Do you expect `seekg` to scan previous 5G and count how many "\r\n" pairs are there to position "properly"? This is again another ugliness of bad decision of MS in DOS era.

Comment: @Denis319199 "Does it mean that I should write two versions of the code: the first that considers \n as \r\n and the second that doesn't?" No you yshould read and write by proper methods like `std::getline` ect which will do that translation for you transparently.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I cannot read through the C++ standard regarding stream positioning now, but, if it is like the C standard, then positioning for non-binary streams is not required to count arbitrary amounts through the file. For example, for a text stream in C, `fseek` is only required to work with `SEEK_SET` and an offset that is 0 or a value returned from a previous `ftell`. As Slava notes, being able to seek to n virtual characters in the middle of a huge file stored in physical characters is unreasonable. If the C++ requirements are similar to those of C, the implementation is not broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, historically text files store 2 symbols for a line break - `\r\n`. When you open a file with  `std::(i|o)fstream` in text mode, read operations replace `\r\n` with `\n`, and vice versa on write operations. `std::istream::seekg()` moves the read pointer in bytes, ignoring that translation. So `std::istream::peek()` gives you only `\n` but it sees `\r\n` in the stream. When you seek by 1 byte, now `std::istream::peek()` only sees one `\n` and gives it to you without translation.

Note you have this artefact due to unusual combination of `peek()` and `seek()`. If you read text by normal operations like `std::istream::get()` `std::getline()` etc you will not have this problem and your application will only see one '\n' symbol on Windows and *nix platforms if you open file in text mode.

Comment: Then, what is the way right to move the pointer back? Should I avoid `seek()` at all? Using `unget()` seems to be a good decision but if I want to return back by 1 symbol. If there are 15 or more symbols, what do I have to do? Put `unget()` into a loop?

Maybe, the function implementation I wrote in the quastion is a bad programming practice. If it is, let me know.

Comment: @Denis319199 not sure why you need `seek` at all and not reading text stream proper way. Despite this artifact you create other potential problems - for example your app will have issues reading redirected output of another program etc. Not sure why you need to return back any symbols.